# Spacing between wordpress menu items

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the issue of the menu items being displayed like this: [The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAsz6.png)

and I can't figure out how to get spacing between them, as wordspacing breaks in the middle part as it thinks its a word, padding and margins just make it around the whole menu. Is there a way I can select each menu item individually and then apply padding around them to seperate them? Heres my current code:

(The code paster struggles to read that and breaks so sorry for linking as an image)

[The current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wxVU.png)

As for css code, there isn't any as what I've tried doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar li {
padding: whatever value
}
```

You can style those menu items using the list target against the nav class specified 'navbar'

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Can you accept this answer so it may potentially help future people? Thanks!

Comment: How do I do that? I wasn't able to see it anywhere, sorry! -edit (Found it, I think!)